# How to use xml2array get the xml date from a foreach?

Tags: php, xml, foreach, php4

I am now studying xml2array, How to use xml2array get the xml date from a foreach? I can print the data, but can not read anything from the foreach. Thanks.

index.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
$aa = array();
$aa = xml2array(file_get_contents('test.xml'));
//print_r($aa); // Array ( [directory] => Array ( [note] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [to] => Tove [from] => Jani [heading] => Reminder [body] => Don't forget me this weekend! ) [1] => Array ( [to] => Jessie [from] => Rosse [heading] => Notice [body] => Tomorry have a meeting ) ) ) )
foreach ($aa['directory']['note'] as $entry) {
    echo '<div class="to">'.$entry['to'].'</div>';
    //do other thing.
}
?>
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<directory>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
    <to>Jessie</to>
    <from>Rosse</from>
    <heading>Notice</heading>
    <body>Tomorry have a meeting</body>
</note>
</directory>
```

xml2array

```
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'tag') {
    if(!$contents) return array(); 

    if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')) {
        //print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!";
        return array();
    } 

    //Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work
    $parser = xml_parser_create('');
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); # http://minutillo.com/steve/weblog/2004/6/17/php-xml-and-character-encodings-a-tale-of-sadness-rage-and-data-loss
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values);
    xml_parser_free($parser); 

    if(!$xml_values) return;//Hmm... 

    //Initializations
    $xml_array = array();
    $parents = array();
    $opened_tags = array();
    $arr = array(); 

    $current = &$xml_array; //Refference 

    //Go through the tags.
    $repeated_tag_index = array();//Multiple tags with same name will be turned into an array
    foreach($xml_values as $data) {
        unset($attributes,$value);//Remove existing values, or there will be trouble 

        //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope
        // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array).
        extract($data);//We could use the array by itself, but this cooler. 

        $result = array();
        $attributes_data = array(); 

        if(isset($value)) {
            if($priority == 'tag') $result = $value;
            else $result['value'] = $value; //Put the value in a assoc array if we are in the 'Attribute' mode
        } 

        //Set the attributes too.
        if(isset($attributes) and $get_attributes) {
            foreach($attributes as $attr => $val) {
                if($priority == 'tag') $attributes_data[$attr] = $val;
                else $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr'
            }
        } 

        //See tag status and do the needed.
        if($type == "open") {//The starting of the tag '<tag>'
            $parent[$level-1] = &$current;
            if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag
                $current[$tag] = $result;
                if($attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 

                $current = &$current[$tag]; 

            } else { //There was another element with the same tag name 

                if(isset($current[$tag][0])) {//If there is a 0th element it is already an array
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;
                } else {//This section will make the value an array if multiple tags with the same name appear together
                    $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);//This will combine the existing item and the new item together to make an array
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 2; 

                    if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well
                        $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                        unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                    } 

                }
                $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]-1;
                $current = &$current[$tag][$last_item_index];
            } 

        } elseif($type == "complete") { //Tags that ends in 1 line '<tag />'
            //See if the key is already taken.
            if(!isset($current[$tag])) { //New Key
                $current[$tag] = $result;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
                if($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 

            } else { //If taken, put all things inside a list(array)
                if(isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag])) {//If it is already an array... 

                    // ...push the new element into that array.
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result; 

                    if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data) {
                        $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                    }
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; 

                } else { //If it is not an array...
                    $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
                    if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes) {
                        if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well 

                            $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                            unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                        } 

                        if($attributes_data) {
                            $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                        }
                    }
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken
                }
            } 

        } elseif($type == 'close') { //End of tag '</tag>'
            $current = &$parent[$level-1];
        }
    } 

    return($xml_array);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That xml2array function <s>smells like it was built during the PHP4 era</s> came from the comments on the [`xml_parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php) manual page, in ignorance of [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).  SimpleXML is [incredibly easy to use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and tackles this problem with ease.  Example code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach($xml->note as $note) {
    echo '<div class="to">'
       . $note->to
       .'</div>';
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="to">Tove</div><div class="to">Jessie</div>
```

Comment: right, it is for PHP4, not read clearly, Thanks Charles.

Comment: @cj, if you are using PHP4, then you won't have SimpleXML available... though if you *are* using PHP4, then you shouldn't be.  PHP4 has been unsupported for over three years now.

Comment: +1 the only correct answer one could give. just cleaning up this xml2array mess a little. And I think as well it's from the PHP 4 era. `xml_parse` was part of common PHP excercise training books those years and they tend to leftover longer in teaching, so I really guess even if written in a comment on PHP.net this is PHP 4 code.